# I cant get LongLister Toolkit in my system

Tags: windows-phone-7, longlistselector

Hi I got following error 
  I added reference from phone.controls.assembly.toolkit but it doesnt work

```
The tag 'LongListSelector' does not exist in XML namespac 'clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit'.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new reference to your library, or in this case, your toolkit, you must also add a reference in your XAML code. 
For eg:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

So in your XAML page, go right to the top, you will see a couple lines like the one above. 
type xmlns:toolkit="LINK TO YOUR TOOLKIT"

When you type xmlns, intellisense will automatically prompt you to a list of available references. You can scroll down to find it.

Make sure you add a unique name like 'toolkit' or 'tool' after xmlns. So to access the LongListSelector, all you have to do is type

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector />
```